# Visual Studio "No Source Available" and Red Underlines bug, compiles fine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm debugging my code in visual studio 10, I press f11 step into my own function (which by the way is in the SAME source cpp file as the current function) and I always get "No source available"!!

Then I tried putting a breakpoint in said function and when I run visual studio it breakpoints and says: "No source available"

I can step over the function but I can't step into it

Another problem that may or may not be related is that every 5 minutes, Visual Studio 10 will suddenly for no reason stop recognizing all of my variables and functions, giving all of them a red underline. It will still compile fine. But the red underlines will say unrecognized variable etc. Then I just right click on one of them, click "go to definition", it brings me to the definition and when I go back to the original window all the red lines have magically disappeared! This does not seem right; forcing visual studio 10 to just take me to the definitions will suddenly make it realize that they exist? Then 5 minutes later the red underlines appear again!

Comment: The problem has fixed itself! I don't think I did anything. I'm beginning to hate this program more and more.

Comment: still getting the red underlines though

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS BACK! I DEFINITELY DID NOT CHANGE ANYTHING AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010, click on "Project, Rescan Solution". The red underscores go away (for now, at least  :o).

The red underscores started appearing a few days ago, two years after I began using VS2010.

With respect to your "No source available", did you by any chance disable debugging info for that particular module? (See "Properties").